# Can you check if a JavaScript number is 32 bits?

Tags: javascript, v8

A lesson learned from libs like [asm.js](https://github.com/asm-js) and one of [Brendan Eich's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) many talks is that JavaScript's 32-bit integers are *much* faster than its default [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point numbers, *provided they're used consistently*.

I'm writing a video game that exclusively uses [V8](https://v8.dev/) and would like to benchmark 32-bit ints in critical areas, and have learned that we can easily force a value to become 32-bit internally by using a bitwise operator, for example:

```
const myValue = 12 | 0;
```

Of course, the benchmark is only valid if I know something hasn't accidentally turned it into a float somewhere. I would like to write tests that verify this. Is it possible to reliably confirm that a variable is in fact currently stored as a 32-bit integer?

**EDIT:**
Note that I'm not looking for a way of removing decimal points. Functions like `Math.floor()` and `Math.trunc()` can do that already (testable via `x === Math.floor(x)`). What I'm looking for is specifically exploiting non-obvious intricacies, such as that a browser engine will sometimes treat a number as float, but other times treat a number as a 32-bit integer (`x = 3` is NOT (necessarily) an integer in JavaScript). A real world example of where 32-bit coercion speeds things up is with code like `~~number` which is [insane amounts faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/10194/0/mathfloor-vs-alternatives) than `Math.floor(number)`, but only works on numbers smaller than 2,147,483,647 (because beyond that, you're [overflowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246373/discussion-on-question-by-aggregate1166877-can-you-check-if-a-javascript-number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here.

> Is it possible to reliably confirm that a variable is in fact currently stored as a 32-bit integer?

Not from JavaScript.

Not with special engine introspection features either; one reason is that this will change depending on circumstances. For example, a baseline tier (interpreter or simple compiler) might well make different decisions about how to store things compared to an optimizing compiler that kicks in later.

Speaking of the latter, the one thing you can do is inspect generated optimized code in V8 using `--print-opt-code` (with a build that has disassembler support enabled). That's rather tedious though.

There is also a crucial difference between

- extremely-short-term storage of intermediate computation results between subsequent operations inside a function. V8's optimizing compiler frequently uses 32-bit representation for these; that happens fully automatically, without you doing anything in particular.
- longer-term storage of final computation results in function return values, object properties, arrays, global/outer-scope variables and so on. V8 never uses 32-bit integer representation for any of these.
  (Note 1: The one necessary exception to this is `Int32Array`s, but before you get too excited, keep in mind that TypedArrays have both strengths and weaknesses; in particular they're more optimized for having a few big-ish long-lived arrays, whereas plain old `Array`s are overall faster for having many small-ish short-lived arrays.)
  (Note 2: This may or may not change over time.)
  (Note 3: V8 uses 31-bit tagged integers whenever it can. Just like 32-bit representation for short-lived intermediates, there's no way for you to observe this directly.)

> A lesson learned from libs like asm.js and one of Brendan Eich's many talks is that JavaScript's 32-bit integers are much faster than its default IEEE 754 floating point numbers, provided they're used consistently.

I don't think that statement holds up to scrutiny. Avoiding int<->float conversions certainly helps performance, but there are many cases where sticking with floats is no slower than sticking with ints.
(Other nitpicks: asm.js is not a library, Brendan is not exactly an authority on JavaScript performance, and the term "JavaScript's 32-bit integers" misleadingly suggests that JavaScript has 32-bit integers that you can choose to use, which it does not have.)

> we can easily force a value to become 32-bit internally by using a bitwise operator, for example: `const myValue = 12 | 0;`

Not quite. As far as JavaScript semantics are concerned, there is no difference between `12` and `12 | 0`. As far as implementation details are concerned, in V8 `const v = 12 | 0;` is constant-folded by the parser and hence is exactly equivalent to `const v = 12;` (or to `const v = 12.0;` for that matter).

The asm.js-style pattern you probably meant to refer to here is to put `| 0` annotations *after operations*, as in `let x = (y+z)|0`. That does indeed have an effect: it changes observable semantics, *and* most modern engines' optimizing compilers will understand it as a hint that it's probably most convenient/efficient to keep the value in an integer register. It's still not a way to *force* integer representation, but it's a *hint* that integer representation is likely a good choice.

> code like `~~number` which is [insane amounts faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/10194/0/mathfloor-vs-alternatives) than `Math.floor(number)`

That's a prime example of an utterly misleading microbenchmark. One telltale sign is: when you see upwards of a billion operations per second, it's a safe bet that the optimizing compiler has completely optimized away your test and you're measuring nothing at all. Besides, measurethat.net's framework has been shown to produce bogus results in the past; I don't feel like spending an hour right now to figure out what weirdness is going on this time, aside from dead-code elimination my guess would be the that the slow case spends so much time allocating heap numbers that the `floor` operations barely show up on a profile. **Before drawing *any* useful conclusions from *any* microbenchmark, you *must* understand what it's actually doing under the hood!** Profiling it is the bare minimum. Inspecting generated code is better. The various JS benchmarking sites out there all utterly fail at this basic requirement.

As a quick counter-example, the following two functions compile to exactly the same optimized code:

```
function f() { for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) i = ~~i; }
function g() { for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) i = Math.floor(i); }
```

If you change the loop bodies to `~~(i + 0.1)` and `Math.floor(i + 0.1)`, then both versions will perform conversions to float and back, so then the example doesn't serve as an argument in support of any "integers are faster" claim. There *will* be a 20% difference in favor of `~~` in that case, but (a) that isn't exactly "insane", and (b) it's due to `Math.floor` having to execute a few more machine instructions to get cases like `-0` and `NaN` right, which `~~` can just truncate to `0`.

---

Regarding things said in comments:

> `(3 | 0) === (3.1 - 0.1) // true`

That only proves that in JavaScript, all numbers behave as if they were doubles. It doesn't tell you *anything* about how the engine stores numbers internally.

> the Number type (the **only** kind of number that exist in javascript)

Well, there are also BigInts nowadays. But since BigInts have to worry about potentially getting *big* (and also because they haven't received as much optimization attention yet), they're not faster than Numbers for small values.

> you'd have to look at the bytecode produced by the optimiser

Almost. Bytecode is not optimized. The optimizing compiler produces machine code, not bytecode.

> you said that `3.0` is a 32-bit int, which is (by spec) completely wrong (it's a 64-bit IEEE 754 float)

It's tricky. By JS spec, all numbers are 64-bit floats. This question was about 32-bit storage chosen by the engine though, and `3.0` can absolutely be stored as a 32-bit integer by an engine. V8's parser does not distinguish between `3.0` and `3`, and V8 will usually initially store it as a 31-bit (sic!) integer. But there's no way you could tell -- there must not be; because per JS spec, all numbers must behave as if represented by 64-bit floats.

> This is actually for an already-completed indie video game [...] I thought, why not squeeze out an extra ~2% performance if possible? It's (possibly premature) optimization that I can definitely do without, but I thought experimenting couldn't hurt

That information would have belonged in the original question, because it provides relevant framing for what is or isn't a helpful answer.
Experimenting with something that doesn't move the needle is a waste of time; whether that qualifies as "hurt" is up to your definition.
As explained above, you can't check for internal representation choices, but you can provide hints. If you have significant amounts of computation that could remain in the integer domain, an experiment you could do is to add `| 0` after these operations and see if that makes a difference.
If I was in your shoes, I would first use profiling to see if the functions in question even matter in the big picture.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to write this up. Thanks for this, this information is invaluable.